# java.util.logging.logger create multiple log files by adding number after log filename

Tags: java, logging

i have a problem of rotation of log filename when using java.util.logging.logger in tomcat.

```
private Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class.getName());
private FileHandler fh = null; 
Log log = new Log();

private void writeLog(String terminalId, String date_time, String msg){
    log.isExists();
    fh =  new FileHandler(log.fullPath(), true);
    fh.setLevel(Level.INFO);
    fh.setFormatter(new MyLogFormatter());
    LOGGER.addHandler(fh);

    LOGGER.setUseParentHandlers(false);
    LOGGER.setLevel(Level.INFO);
    LOGGER.info("Terminal: " + terminalId);
    LOGGER.info("Time: " + date_time);
    LOGGER.info("message: " + msg);
}

public test() {
    writeLog(mapXML.get("terminalId"), mapXML.get("date_time"), "successful");
}
```

In the above code, the `log.fullPath()` is like "/usr/desktop/2015-05-13.log"

After i execute test() multiple times, multiple files such as

> 2015-05-13.log, 2015-05-13.log.1, 2015-05-13.log.2, 2015-05-13.log.3

are generated.

In the 2015-05-13.log, it contains the total messages, and the file with number only contains the message of that execution.

I know if restarting tomcat after each execution of `test()`, only 2015-05-13.log is created.

But i can not restart tomcat after each execution. So how to let it generate only one log file?

Comment: have you closed the file handler after working on it ?

Comment: @Vinayak Pingale No, i do not close the file handler after working on it.

Comment: @Vinayak Pingale the problem is solved after i flush and close file handler, thanks.

Comment: Then it sees that there is already a handler open on that file and opens a new handler with a number after the file name. You should only have one handler.

Comment: First try to close the `Filehandler` and then run it.
second you can use following constructor for gaining the FileHandler. `FileHandler fh = new FileHandler
 ( "path" + "logfileName", 0, 1, false);`

Comment: You didn't close the handler `fh` after writing, as a result the log file remains locked and not available the next time it's needed. A new file is then created as a result.

Answer (score 6):

This is coming late but am still posting for those who might find this relevant.

The problem is because you didn't close `FileHandler fh` after writing. The first log file created remains locked and not available, as a result, a new file is then created and appended a number to avoid conflict.

Simply add `fh.close();` after `LOGGER.info("message: " + msg);` to close the handler.

Comment: But, what is I have a static LOG instance? Closing it would cause further logging disabled, right?

Comment: Yes, Logging after the `FileHandler` has been closed will no longer work, you'll have to re-initialize and attach the handler.